# How do I access an mxml component through an actionscript variable in adobe flex?

Tags: actionscript

Lets say I have a button

```
 <s:Button id = "button1" label="Click" click = "buttonHandler()"/>
```

and I have another button that is supposed to remove this button by calling the following function

```
 protected function remove_Button(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
      var button1:Button = ?????
      this.removeChild(button1);
 }
```

how do I first declare the variable to be the same button in the mxml file?

Answer (score 0):

If the button and corresponding code for the second button are in the same MXML document, you can simply refer to the first button by the ID that you have assigned it, `button1` in this case.

Example.mxml:

```
<s:Button id = "button1" label="Click" click = "buttonHandler()"/>
<s:Button label="Remove 1st Button" click = "remove_Button(event)"/>

// this code appears inside a script block in Example.mxml
protected function remove_Button(event:MouseEvent):void
{
        // no need to declare button1 as a variable, that has already been
        // done in the 1st <Button> object above
        this.removeChild(button1);
}
```

It should be noted that any object you declare with an MXML tag is a public variable of that MXML document. So if the second button is in a different MXML document/class then you can still access it through the ID that you have assigned (ie: `button1`).

Answer (score 0):

In remove_Button function write `this.removeElement(button1);` if your skin not supported `this.removeChild` function.